# Techno-House theme where interpreter naming Roman Emperors in the lyrics

Tags: identify-this-song, house, techno

I was reading this [question on Christianity StackExchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/41912) and suddenly I remembered hear a song which:

- It was interpreted by a female *(I suppose that by her voice).*
- The music's genre was electronic or house or [eurodance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurodance) *(I'm not familiar indicating the diferences in techno music).*
- Part of the lyrics (maybe it's chorus) was *naming a serie of roman emperors*; some like that:

> *claudius, aureluis, ....*

I already tried search and with no results were found.

*N.B Additional data (year or production, similar theme songs, etc) are unknown for me.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Amor Infinitus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OSfTxXaB5s)" by Imperio matches your description.